# Javac не генерирует warning на @Deprecated

Tags: java, javac

Компилирую такой код

```
public class MyClass {
    /**
        An entry point for entire program
        @param args command line arguments
        @version 1.0 SNAPSHOT
        @see <a href='https://www.google.com'>google.com</a>
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting ...");
        printHelloWorld();
    }
    @Deprecated()
    public static void printHelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

командой `javac MyClass.java`. Версия компилятора 11.0.2.

Однако никаких сообщений о использовании deprecated метода не получаю. 
Компилируется без всяких сообщений. После декомпиляции полученного class-файла получаю

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class MyClass
{

    public MyClass()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Starting ...");
        printHelloWorld();
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated Method printHelloWorld is deprecated
     */

    public static void printHelloWorld()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Аннотация `@Deprecated` превратилась в тег javadoc-a. Тоже немного непонятно почему. Если это сделал декомпилятор из-за наличия аннотации, то почему он её саму убрал? Декомпилировал с помощью jad.

Почему компилятор не выдает предупреждений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Однако никаких сообщений о использовании deprecated метода не получаю.

Попробуйте вынести метод `printHelloWorld` в другой класс и использовать его. Тогда предупреждение появится. Пометка об устаревании имеет смысл только в отношении публичного API, а не к использованию классом своих собственных методов.

> Аннотация @Deprecated превратилась в тег javadoc-a. Тоже немного
>   непонятно почему. Если это сделал декомпилятор из-за наличия
>   аннотации, то почему он её саму убрал?

Вероятно ваш декомпилятор её теряет, так как в байткоде она остаётся:

```
  public static void printHelloWorld();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         3: ldc           #3                  // String Hello world!
         5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         8: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 63: 0
        line 64: 8
    Deprecated: true
    RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
      0: #18()                                // Ljava/lang/Deprecated;
```

Comment: Не знал, что байткод сохраняет инструкцию `@Deprecated` - как говорится, век живи век учись!

Comment: @Barmaley честно говоря, я тоже был уверен, что у неё retention=SOURCE. Теперь любопытно почему нет.